# Kill a child process that has detached from the shell

Tags: ruby, shell, exec

I want to control many different Sinatra apps from a central (Sinatra) app.

The problem I have is no matter which way I exec/spawn/fork the call to start it, I cannot get the pid of the Sinatra server so that I can kill (:int) it?

This is due to my shell exec string, which contains a few other commands first, so I get the pid of the first.
My command string is like

```
command = source ~/.profile; rbenv #{ver}; some_env=1234 ruby app.rb
```

So I get the pid of the sh process of the sourcing command.

The question is, how can I get the pid of the ruby command launched above?

I am currently using spawn, but have tried most others as well, but I don't think that is the problem!?

```
pid = Process.spawn(command)
pid # => 1234
```

The ruby app itself starts

```
$ ps aux
1234 sh -c . ~/.profile; shell_script
4567 shell_script
```

I want to know 4567!?

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way of getting your '4567', but you should be able to make your process have the same pid as `Process.spawn` returns.

Try ending your command with an `exec` rather than a straight call to ruby, i.e.:

```
source ~/.profile; rbenv #{ver}; export some_env=1234; exec ruby app.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check whether the process "shell_script" is a child of "sh -c . ~/.profile; shell_script".you can check this through "ps -axgf" command.

if it is a parent then u can use the group id of pid 1234 (get it form the output of ps -axgf) to kill the child with pid 4567 using this command .

kill -9 -1234(assumming 1234 is the group id)